# vb.net Excel column to listbox error

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
 For rng = 2 To row
        name = range(row, 1)
        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Select * FROM bricom_users.codes where firstcode = '" & name & "';"
            COMM = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = COMM.ExecuteReader
            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0
            While READER.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While
            If name = "" Or name = "SKU" Then

            End If
            If count = 1 Then
                Query = "Select secondcode FROM bricom_users.codes where firstcode = '" & name & "';"
                COMM = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
                READER = COMM.ExecuteReader
                Dim gr = READER.GetString("secondcode")
                ListBox1.Items.Add(gr)
            End If
            If count = 0 Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(name)
            End If
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    Next

End Sub
```

This is code where I have the problems. I get nullreference on name = range(row,1)

What I want to do is to get all the data from first column, for each row (starting with second). For every cell, the app should verify if there is same code in the database. If it found the code, this code should get the info from secondcode, where firstcode = ... (from Excel cell).

If this code isn't in database, then the app should insert in listbox this code, without changes.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `Range` is incorrect. It expects a *named* location such as:

```
Range("A1")
Range("NamedRange")
' In your case.
Range("A" & row).Value.ToString
```

To use coordinates, you need to use the `Cells` property:

```
name = Cells(row, 1).Value.ToString
```

---

As for the rest of your logic, it would be helpful to see some of your data but once you get past the syntax error you should be able to step through your code and get a clearer picture of what is going on.

A few notes though:

- Use parameters in your query. Appending `name` as a string is dangerous and makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
- Since you only want a count, you might want to consider updating your query

:

```
Query = "Select Count(*) FROM bricom_users.codes where firstcode = @name;"
COMM = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
COMM.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name)
Dim count As Integer = COMM.ExecuteScalar ' This will give the total count.
```

Comment: Added:
name = Sheet.Cells(row, 1) but got this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
(sheet is my worksheet)

Also, this application is only for me (I want to make an app which get the codes and other elements from excel, check it if they are/aren't in database and after it post it into listbox, so I could export it in csv) so I don't really care about security (only I will have access to this app). Thanks.

Comment: @InDeepTerror - Ah yes, since you are running it in VB.Net, you will need to use the `.Value` property. See my updated answer.

Comment: @InDeepTerror - What is `name` declared as? (Assuming this line gives you the error).

Comment: The     name is declared as string

Comment: @InDeepTerror - See updated answer. Depending on if you have option strict enabled, you may need to append the `.ToString` method.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry but this was a bit stupid from me. I didn't saw (a lot of declaring variables) and I declared name as integer, not string :( That's why I got an error, but now I have 1 more problem: 
When I run the app, first code is appear, but after it I got the error on same lane: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication4.exe
can you help me with this? Thanks.